# PHP: How to Insert an Image in a new row for every 10th row in the MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert a new random image in a row (all by itself) after 10 rows of data have been populated.

I'm thinking I should input something like this:

```php
if($counter % 10 == 0) {
  echo 'image file';
}
```

But not really sure how to incorporate this in my code:

```php
 echo "<table border='1' CELLPADDING=5 STYLE='font-size:13px'>";
 echo "<tr> <td><H3>No.</H3></td><td><H3>Date</H3></td>";
 echo "<td><H3>First Name</H3></td> <td><H3>Last Name</H3></td>";
 echo "<td><H3>City</H3></td><td><H3>Province</H3></td></tr>";

 //declaring counter
 $count=0;

 // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {
     //counter equals
     $count=$count+1;   

     // Print out the contents of each row into a table
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $count;
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['DateIn'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['FirstName'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['LastName'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['City'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['Province_State'];
     echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table border='1' CELLPADDING=5 STYLE='font-size:13px'>";
echo "<tr> <td><H3>No.</H3></td><td><H3>Date</H3></td><td><H3>First Name</H3></td> <td>    <H3>Last Name</H3></td> <td><H3>City</H3></td><td><H3>Province</H3></td></tr>";

//declaring counter
$count=0;

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {

//counter equals
$count++;  

//insert an image every 10 rows
if($count==10){
    $count=0;
    echo 'yourimage.jpg';
}

// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "</td><td>";
echo $count;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['DateIn'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['FirstName'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['LastName'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['City'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Province_State'];
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Nothing, each to their own I suppose.

Comment: Yep, with mod you won't need to reset the counter.  Realistically it'll work either way and there's no huge efficiency boost or anything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments.....How exactly do I incorporate this...Would I put the entire if counter == 10 on top and put all the echo rows inside?

Comment: @dweiss technically speaking, mod is slower than == ... but we're talking about PHP of course ;-)

Comment: :) I'm not going to try to pretend I know a ton about that stuff.  But, hey, you gotta include the assignment that becomes required, too!

Comment: The issue I have is that I want to have a running total rows displayed as well.  So, when I use this code, it resets the values.  Otherwise, the code works great.

Comment: I just set up another counter, this one for the images, and all is fine.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

if($counter % 10 == 0) {
    echo 'image file';
    }
10, not 100 :).  Put this after your $count=$count+1 statement in a td colspan=however many columns you have.

Comment: And, just to clarify, that will execute the code in the if statement after every ten iterations.

Comment: Hi Dan.  Maybe it was 100 and he just edited it to 10.  If you'd like to come to my address, I still have his comment copied in my clipboard.

Comment: My clipboard:   if($counter % 100 == 0) {
    echo 'image file';
    } so I guess either my page rendered it incorrectly or it was edited.  I'm pretty sure this site is about getting a question answered.  I hear AIM has some cool chat rooms if you guys want to take this elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question, or do you need some more help?  I tried to be specific in my answer but I can be pretty unexpressive sometimes :P.  you want if($counter % 10 == 0) { echo '<td colspan="total_columns_here">image_here</td>';} and you want to put this just below $count=$count+1

Comment: Thanks.  I have it working but it is showing an image in between each row.  I think I read something that this happens when you have the count initialized as 0;  I am displaying the row count so I really can't change that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope.  I just changed count=1 and it still displays every second row.  I needed to add <tr></tr> also.  Without it, it populated in a column.

Comment: So, I have this:  if($counter % 10 == 0) {
  echo '<tr><td colspan="6">image file</td></tr>';
  }

Comment: Yep!  You don't want an else because you don't want to end up skipping a row of data.  So, you want to display that as a standalone row and continue another <tr> for the regular iteration!

Comment: So, I have all the data and an image between each row.  I feel I am so close.

Comment: I got it working.  I created a second counter and then used this code: if($counter_for_image==10){
    $counter_for_image=0;
    echo '<tr><td colspan="6">yourimage.jpg</td></tr>';
}

Comment: Why did you need a second counter?  Could you possibly attach your code again?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Here is the completed code that works (however, I still can't get the random image to show, but I can get an image :-)

```
    echo "<table border='1' CELLPADDING=5 STYLE='font-size:13px'>";
    echo "<tr> <td><H3>No.</H3></td><td><H3>Date</H3></td><td><H3>First Name</H3></td> <td><H3>Last Name</H3></td> <td><H3>City</H3></td><td><H3>Province</H3></td></tr>";

    //declaring counter for data
    $count=0;

    //declaring counter for random image
    $counter_for_image=0;

    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {

    //counter for actual count
    $count=$count+1;    

    //counter for image count
    //so I can reset count and
    //not affect actual count
    $counter_for_image++;



    /* does not work
    // start random image code
    $images = array(
    0 => '1.jpg',
    1 => '2.jpg',
    );
    $image = $images[ rand(0,(count($images)-1)) ];
    $randomimage = "<img src=\"/http://wwww.my site.com/storm/images/".$image."\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" />";
    //print($output);
    // end random image code
    */

    // start every 10th row image display code  
    if($counter_for_image==10){
    $counter_for_image=0;

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><center><img src="http://www.mysite.com/storm/images/eric.jpg"/></center></td></tr>';

    /* would use this if I could get random image to work
    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><center>';
    print($randomimage);
    echo '</center></td></tr>';
    */

    } // end every 10th row image display code  


    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $count;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['DateIn'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['FirstName'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['LastName'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['City'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Province_State'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
```